# Mac keybindings not working in OneNote

Tags: macos, onenote

I've remapped my home and end keys to behave like Windows using https://damieng.com/blog/2015/04/24/make-home-end-keys-behave-like-windows-on-mac-os-x/

Shift+end highlights text from the cursor to the end of the line.
Shift+home highlights to the beginning of the line.

This works in all applications I've used since remapping - EXEPT MS OneNote. Anyone know why OneNote might behave differently? MS Outlook, MS Word, Mac Text Edit, Mac Notes - all work as I'd like.

What would cause OneNote to respond with an error beep as compared to the other apps? I don't have any custom key mappings in system/keyboard setup for OneNote.

MacOS: 12.3.1
MacBook Pro M1, 14"

Answer (score 1):

Because, as the article you link says:

> This remapping does the following in most Mac apps - including Chrome
> (some apps manage their key handling directly):

OneNote apparently does.